# Why "int" is not a class like "String"?

Tags: java, class, oop, reference, value-type

I know this is a weird question and maybe a little vague. Because I myself isn't sure about what I'm really missing. But please hear me out.

In java, there are :

1. `value types` (like `int`, `char`, ...).
2. `reference types` (like `string`, `user-defined classes`,...)

```
> int age; 
> String name;
```

I know that the value types are primitive and simple unlike the ref type.

**But why is `int` here just a deceleration keyword and `String` is an actual class?**

*I hope this sounds right. I know it's probably not the right question to ask but maybe you can help me figure out what I don't know that I'm missing.*

Comment: Basically, a String is a class because the primitive char exists; a String is an array of chars: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2099257/why-is-there-no-primitive-type-for-string

Comment: 1. The short answer to a question like _why ...?_ is usually _by design_.  2.  There are wrapper classes for primitive value types: `Integer` for `int`, `Character` for `char`, `Double` for `double` etc.

Comment: @LuckyBandit74, thank you for sharing the link. It had many useful information.

Comment: @AlexRudenko, 1. by "*by design*" you mean architecture? 2. I will look up the wrapper class because I don't know what it is. If I knew about them I would've probably asked why don't we use *Integer variable;* but I guess that's not how it works.

Comment: 1. _By design_ I meant by the design of Java programming language.  [There's an explanation why primitive types exist in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14477743/why-are-there-primitive-datatype-in-java/14477916): _The main reason primitive data type are there because, creating object, allocating heap is too costly and there is a performance penalty for it._   2. [Another explanation why primitives are supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2063556/when-we-have-wrappers-classes-why-primitives-are-supported)

Comment: @AlexRudenko That's great. Thank you for sharing! :)

Answer (score 3):

Unlike `int`, `char` etc which are primitive data types, `String` is a derived datatype as it is derived from primitives (in this case `char`). After all String is an array of characters (`char[]`).

A Java String is an object of the class `java.lang.String`.

> The String class represents character strings. All string literals in
> Java programs, such as "abc", are implemented as instances of this
> class.

Refer to the ***[documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html).***

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes indeed, and I have checked that documentation. It was the `String.class` that lead me to this point. Meanwhile, int and other primitives didn't have a class file used in declaring variables. That was the actual question I had. Because if `int` is not a class, then what it is? Which the answer to this is just a primitive data type **that doesn't NEED a class**. Which I knew but for some reason I got confused for my lack of knowledge in data structure and computer architecture.